# What are the "points" in my rabbit's mouth that my vet is referring to?

Tags: health, rabbits, biology

My vet was looking in my rabbit's mouth and said she had a couple of "points" that might need to be addressed on the next visit.  I forgot to ask for clarification and am wondering what he was talking about.

What are these "points", and why are they in my rabbit's mouth?

Comment: are you sure a point is a physical thing (like a tooth) and not a synonym for "issue" or "problem"?

Comment: @Oldcat, yes and Ashley has the answer.

Answer (score 6):

It could likely be a couple of things. First, it could be that they meant there are a few problem areas in the mouth, but forgot to give you specifics, using "points" as a synonym for "areas" or "issues". That seems a little strange, though, that they wouldn't tell you what the issues were.

Did some brief research on rabbit teeth, though, and that brought up a second option of what they could have meant. They might have meant that there are [molar spurs](http://www.bio.miami.edu/hare/dental.html) on your rabbit's teeth. These are sharp points that stick out from the tooth, and can cause pain to the rabbit, as they risk digging into or cutting the rabbit's mouth. These are caused by uneven wear on the tooth. You will need someone trained in rabbit dentistry to deal with the issue - there are a [few things](http://www.plymouthvets.co.uk/library/rabbits/dental-disease.shtml) they can do, such as using a burr or something like that to smooth down the spur, or in worse cases, removal of the tooth might be necessary.