# How fast do rabbits teeth grow, is it faster the cavities?

Tags: health, rabbits, growing

The two existing questions and answers [What are the "points" in my rabbit's mouth that my vet is referring to?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/) & [Why is adding hay to a rabbit's diet important?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/551) talk a little bit about rabbits teeth growing.  We know from experience the people get dental cavities, and it seems that most pets can as well.

How fast do a rabbits teeth grow?

Do I need to be concerned about dental cavities, or do their teeth grow faster than a cavity can form?

Answer (score 2):

From [WHY DO RABBITS' TEETH NEVER STOP GROWING?](http://animals.pawnation.com/rabbits-teeth-never-stop-growing-10459.html):

A rabbit's teeth grow 3-5 inches annually. From the below quotes we can see that a rabbit's teeth grow very fast.

> The extensive chewing and gnawing that rabbits regularly engage in
>   balances the perpetual tooth growth. If a rabbit’s teeth were not
>   open-rooted, they would wear down very quickly, eventually rendering
>   chewing such dietary requirements extremely difficult.

**And:**

> In the wild, rabbits have unlimited access to the vegetation that
>   keeps their growing teeth under control. Pet rabbits are much more
>   limited and require continuous supply of timothy hay.

Because their teeth grow so fast and their teeth engage with fibrous vegetation that normally cleans teeth, concerns for Dental Caries are very low. But that does not mean impossible, I have heard nothing indicating Rabbit rates of cavities, but because their teeth grow out and the damaged teeth would be gone the risk would be low.

[This post](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Rabbits-703/Rabbit-Cavities.htm) supports my thoughts that Rabbit Cavities are basically impossible.
Like the post says Cavities are unlikely because of teeth growth rate, but damage and abscesses to the jaw are more likely, as are ingrown teeth that don't erupt properly.